# v-select with filter dosent work

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I create one v-select but I want to filter what I will show

this is my html:

```
<v-select
  :items="formaPagamentoList"
  :filter="filtarFormaPagamento"
  item-text="nome"
  v-model="formPagamentoSelecionada"
  item-value="id"
  placeholder="Selecione uma Forma de Pagamento"
  single-line
  ></v-select>
```

and this is my js

```
data: () => ({
    formPagamentoSelecionada: null,
    totalAdicionado: 0,
    valorInformado: null,
    formaPagamentoList: [],
    formPagamentoAdicionada: [],
    alert: false,
    filtarFormaPagamento(item, queryText, itemText) {
      console.log('hi');
      return item.credito;//this is a boolean prop in my object
    },
  }),
```

my 'hi' don`t show in console and my select are not filtered.

tks

Comment: `filtarFormaPagamento` should be in `methods` perhaps, and not in `data`?

Comment: I already tried, and when I put in methods nothing happen too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it's currently a bug(`v.1.0.17`), and doesn't work without `autocomplete` prop.

Track the related github issue here:
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/3815